# Setting optional elements in mapping in Biztalk?

Tags: biztalk

I have a mapping with a input-schema and a outputschema. If I send a xml-file with two fields that are not provided with the schema the element fields are written out, but with empty values. I would like to that it didn't write the elements at all in the output file. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a "Logical Existence" Functoid to only produce the element in the output when it is supplied in the input.

To do this;
a) Drag the logical existence functoid to the mapper surface.
b) Drag a value map functoid to the map surface
c) connect the element from the source schema to the logical existence functoid
d) connect the logical existence functoid to your value mapping functoid.
e) connect the element to your value mapping functoid
f) connect your value mapping functoid to the destination element to conditionally map to.

This says "when i have element X in the source, then map its value to element Y in the destination. otherwise don't perform the mapping".

Do the steps above in order to ensure that the functoid inputs are configured correctly.

HTH